# Is it pointless to add a default value of NULL to a nullable field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that is used to store configurable elements within a system.

For simplicities sake assume this is the table structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[configuration_table] (
    flag            BIT          NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    insert_datetime DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    update_datetime DATETIME              DEFAULT NULL)
```

When an initial insert is completed the time of entry has to be set.

When an update is made, the update date time will be set to track when the update to the flag occurred.

Is it pointless to set the default value on a nullable field to NULL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a matter of opinion.  Clearly, explicitly declaring something to use the default behavior is *redundant*.  Sometimes, redundancy is desirable for clarity.  Sometimes, it is just verbiage.  In this case, I think that is a matter of opinion.

Comment: The advantage of doing so is that it saves some typing on insert queries.

Comment: There are many advantages as to why and why not. I suggest you review your architecture and your purpose and if you have something more constructive / conclusive, you can post again to see if your design approach is right. But to just answer this specifically to one table will not be enough.

Comment: @DanBracuk Doing it won't save you any typing, you can always omit nullable columns on inserts. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: yes it's pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL server there is not advantage in doing that, because:

- When you omit a nullable column from the field list of an `INSERT` it will use `NULL` when no default constraint value is defined:

  ```
  -- update_datetime will be null when no default constraint is defined on that column
  insert into configuration_table (flag, insert_datetime)
    values (1,'20171209')
  ```
- If you use the keyword `DEFAULT` as value for inserting the default value it will use `NULL` when no constraint is defined:

  ```
  -- update_datetime will be also null when no default constraint is defined on the column
  insert into configuration_table (flag, insert_datetime, update_datetime)
    values (1,'20171209',default)
  ```

In fact, there is a small disadvantage in doing that because that column will have an unneeded dependency on the constraint (for example, if the column is `int` and you want to `ALTER` the column to `bigint` it will fail because of the constraint).

So yes, it's pointless to set the default value on a nullable field to `NULL`, at least in SQL Server (maybe other RDBMS have quirks that made it useful).